# Layout Help in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout

I am a college student just starting to learn how to program on Android, and I'm working with Android Studio. I'm relatively new, but understand a very, very general idea on how some things work thus far. I was tasked with designing a tip calculator app, with three text fields for the user to enter into: a total bill, a tip percentage, and a split field if the user wants to break up the check evenly among different people, with the default split being just one person. Only the functionality of the app is specified, not the layout or aesthetics.

I have a pretty general idea of where I want to go with the way I want my app to look. I want my three entry boxes to be aligned to the far left, directly on top of each other, and display the total amount per person at the very bottom of the screen automatically displayed after the the three fields are entered, with default values of the total bill, and tip percentage being 0, and the default split being 1.

So far, I am having trouble aligning each entry field to the far left. My first field starts left, then the next starts directly to its right by default. I can't quite figure out how to stack them one on top of the other. Under the design tab, I am able to place one field below another, but trying to move one to the left swaps the other to the right, and vice-versa. What syntax in the xml file of the activity must I change to have them align one on top of the other? I've been looking at a few tutorial sites on layouts, but they don't quite explain how to implement my specific idea. How do I do this?

I appreciate the help

**Edit**: something like this

[image]

Comment: Can you post a photo to show us how your expected view looks like?

Comment: @Rami is right. you should post it as at least as a jpeg if you want anyone to be able to help you...

Comment: @SNt sorry about that, I uploaded a general sketch of what I'd like

Comment: I wonder how, he posted that picture with such a reputation score!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a pretty straight forward layout. I'm quite new to Android Studio but have a look at LinearLayout(vertical).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:text="split between"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:text="a tip?"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:text="total"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this suggestion:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Total bill : $"
            android:id="@+id/totalBillTv"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/totalBillEdt"
            android:text="100"
            android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="#ffffff" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Tip % :"
            android:id="@+id/tipTv"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tipEdt"
            android:text="15"
            android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="#ffffff" />
        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Split "
            android:id="@+id/splitTv"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/splitEdt"
            android:text="2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="#ffffff" />
        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Total :"
            android:id="@+id/totalTv"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/totalEdt"
            android:text="57.50"
            android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="#ffffff" />
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**PS:** You can play with `android:textSize="YOUR_VALUE"`, to change the size of texts

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/first_layout"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/total_bill"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/total_bill_label"
            android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
            android:minWidth="90dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Total bill: $"
            android:id="@+id/total_bill_label"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/second_layout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/first_layout"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tip"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tip_label"
            android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
            android:minWidth="90dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Tip: %"
            android:id="@+id/tip_label"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/third_layout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/second_layout"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/split"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/split_label"
            android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
            android:minWidth="40dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Split:"
            android:id="@+id/split_label"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/fourth_layout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/third_layout"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp" >

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/total"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/total_label"
            android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
            android:minWidth="90dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Total:"
            android:id="@+id/total_label"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

If you want to know more about the layouts i used, here's a brief explanation:

I have put every label and the related EditText in a relative layout to be able to align their vertical centers. you can see

```
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

and

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/total_bill_label"
```

in the first layout.

And after that i used alignComponent in relative layouts to align the layouts.

This is the preview of the layout:

[image: Preview of the above layout]

Comment: Your solution works but... for better performance, it's recommended to use LinearLayout (instead of RelativeLayout) if it do the work. Because RelativeLayout do an extra measure that could potentially be fairly costly, specially in complex hierarchy.

Comment: you are right for sure. but this is a layout with just a few (limited) items.